# How do I find the TTF font name for Adobe Normalizer (i.e. Times New Roman)

Tags: pdf, adobe, truetype, postscript, pdfa

I'm trying to use Adobe Normalizer to convert PostScript files to PDF/A.

The problem I am having is that if a font isn't found it is a hard stop. I added the "--ignorestdttfonts=off" and that helps a little bit. Here's what I'm using for my command string:

```
demonorm -efi --ignorestdttfonts=off -r0 -P ICCProfiles\ -B ".\Settings\PDFA1b 2005 RGB.joboptions" +n -O -O c:\NormalizerOutput InputPsFile.ps
```

I am using /Times-Roman in my PostScript file, and I have times.ttf as an installed font, but I am getting this error:

```
%%[ Error: Times-Roman not found. Font cannot be embedded. ]%%
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Given a TTF file, how do I know exactly what font name to use for
   Adobe Normalizer?
2. How do I substitute a font when a font is not found? The default is
   to use Courier, but that doesn't seem to be happening. I explicitly
   added "--allowdefaultfont=on --defaultfont=Courier" but it had no
   effect.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Normalizer will always look for the PostScript font name. Unfortunately unlike other Adobe products it will not create a fontlist (.lst) file where you can easily see the "FontName" and the location of the font file on your system. So you will have to find other ways to get the exact PostScript font name.

An easy way to see PostScript font names is to open the Distiller settings file (joboptions) using Distiller. You want to use Distiller because you want this to open in a GUI. On the left side panel select "Fonts" and under Embedding > Font Source > select C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ (assuming the TTF file is installed here). The window below will list all the fonts in the C:\Windows\Fonts location. The fonts are listed by their PostScript font names. Note that PostScript font names do not appear with spaces. Look for the Times or Times Roman font that you have installed.

This does get quite tricky with Times or Times-Roman. Is your PostScript file (input file) referring to an Type1 or TrueType font?

In the Normalizer documentation (p174) the Times or Times New Roman family appears as:

### Times

- Times-Bold
- Times-BoldItalic
- Times-Italic
- Times-Roman

### Times New Roman

- TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT
- TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT
- TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT
- TimesNewRomanPSMT

Note that Times and Times New Roman are not the same fonts. Times is a Type1 font and if you do not have this font installed on your system then Normalizer is correct in its error "Times-Roman not found. Font cannot be embedded."

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Normalizer, as I understand it (I don't have a copy) is essentially a server version of Acrobat Distiller. It accepts PostScript as an input and delivers PDF files.

So there are several possibilities:

1) Normalizer cannot use TrueType fonts installed on the server. From your description that doesn't seem to be the case, as you say that --ignorestdttfonts 'helps a little bit' (it might be useful to know what improves...)

2) Because the missing font is Times-Roman, its simply not embedding the font because it doesn't need to. The 'base 14' fonts are assumed to be included with any PDF consumer, and they don't need to be included. To be honest, this seems like the most likely, as I would have thought that Adobe would ship the base 14 fonts with the Normalizer.

3) The TrueType font isn't available to Normalizer. You haven't said **how** you installed times.ttf. Did you just install it on the OS (and what OS are you using anyway ?) or did you add it to Normalizer in some fashion ?

4) You may (as you think) have the font name incorrect. The problem is that you cannot use TrueType fonts directly in PostScript. In order to be used in a PostScript program they have to be converted into type 42 fonts. It may be that Normalizer simply can't do that. Do you have any reason to think it can ? If it can, then it may require a TrueType POST table, which is optional and may not be present in your font. However, the font name would be the same as the TrueType font name. The times.ttf *I* have is called "Times New Roman" and is in fact an **OpenType** font. If you want to use a font name with spaces you will have to make a string and convert to name :

```
(Times New Roman) cvn findfont
```

If you want to check the operation of the default font, I would suggest using a font name which is not one of the base 14, eg:

```
%!PS
/NoSuchFont findfont 20 scalefont setfont
10 10 moveto
(Hello World) show
showpage
```

Run that through Normalizer and see what comes out as the font. It may well be that it simply leaves the font request in place of course.

Finally; since this is a commercial product I assume you are entitled to support, wouldn't it be simpler just to ask Adobe ?